# Open Declaration stopped working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm using the Spring Tool Suite version 3.7.3.RELEASE and today the Open Declaration shortcut stopped working out of nowhere for both F3 and Ctrl+Click. I've read a bunch of other similar questions and none of the solutions have been helpful so far. I've tried all of the following:

- Reimport all projects
- Close and reopen all projects
- Restarting Eclipse
- Going into the Preferences and manually setting the Proposals
- Running a maven update with a clean build

When I press F3 over some variable or method name, I get the error pictured below, which is not very descriptive. Any thoughts or ideas on what could be wrong?

[image]

Adding log output:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-06-21 12:05:24.101
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.NameEnvironmentAnswer.<init>([Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/ISourceType;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/AccessRestriction;)V
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.core.codeconversion.ITDAwareNameEnvironment.find(ITDAwareNameEnvironment.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findType(SearchableEnvironment.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.findType(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3227)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2939)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1320)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:952)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.SelectionEngine.select(SelectionEngine.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.codeSelect(Openable.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.codeSelect(CompilationUnit.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.codeSelect_aroundBody0(CompilationUnit.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit$AjcClosure1.run(CompilationUnit.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.itdawareness.ITDAwarenessAspect.ajc$around$org_eclipse_contribution_jdt_itdawareness_ITDAwarenessAspect$6$3f3ffce8proceed(ITDAwarenessAspect.aj:311)
    at org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.itdawareness.ITDAwarenessAspect.ajc$around$org_eclipse_contribution_jdt_itdawareness_ITDAwarenessAspect$6$3f3ffce8(ITDAwarenessAspect.aj:312)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.codeSelect(CompilationUnit.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4415)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4233)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3821)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1119)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1489)
```

This might also be relevant:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-06-21 12:08:52.470
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.NameEnvironmentAnswer.<init>([Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/ISourceType;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/AccessRestriction;)V
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.core.codeconversion.ITDAwareNameEnvironment.find(ITDAwareNameEnvironment.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findType(SearchableEnvironment.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.findType(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3227)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2939)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1320)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:952)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.HierarchyResolver.resolve(HierarchyResolver.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.HierarchyResolver.resolve(HierarchyResolver.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.HierarchyBuilder.buildSupertypes(HierarchyBuilder.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.IndexBasedHierarchyBuilder.build(IndexBasedHierarchyBuilder.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.compute(TypeHierarchy.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.hierarchy.TypeHierarchy.refresh(TypeHierarchy.java:1286)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CreateTypeHierarchyOperation.executeOperation(CreateTypeHierarchyOperation.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.newSupertypeHierarchy(SourceType.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.newSupertypeHierarchy(SourceType.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaLaunchableTester.hasSuperclass(JavaLaunchableTester.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.JavaLaunchableTester.test(JavaLaunchableTester.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.Property.test(Property.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateOr(CompositeExpression.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.OrExpression.evaluate(OrExpression.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.AndExpression.evaluate(AndExpression.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.IterateExpression.evaluate(IterateExpression.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.EnablementExpression.evaluate(EnablementExpression.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.evalEnablementExpression(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.getShortcutsForSelection(LaunchingResourceManager.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.computeLabels(LaunchingResourceManager.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager$1$1.run(LaunchingResourceManager.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: Try creating a new workspace and import the existing projects into it.

Comment: Can I just delete some metadata in the existing workspace to get it back to normal? There is no direct fix?

Comment: `org.eclipse.ajdt.core.codeconversion.ITDAwareNameEnvironment` is trying to use a constructor of `NameEnvironmentAnswer` that does not exist. I don't know what `ITDAwareNameEnvironment` is as it is not part of standard Eclipse, but it has a bug.

Comment: Looks like AJDT (AspecyJDevelopment Tooling) may be broken by some api changes in eclipse JDT. @greg-449 is probably right this is a bug. Or it could be somehow version of AJDT and JDT have been installed together that aren't compatible. When the problem started, was that anywhere close to you installing updates/packages from eclipse update sites or marketplace?

Comment: If it is a problem of having installed something that pulled in incompatible versions of JDT/AJDT the easiest thing to do is probably to go back to a 'clean' install of STS.

Comment: @Kris I hadn't added anything new at all. It just seemed to stop working very suddenly. It actually did happen fairly soon after I imported a new maven project. I had an existing project and added a new project to the workspace. It could be related?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue. This happens when you accidentally install AspectJ Development Tools in Eclipse Neon using the AJDT update site for Eclipse Mars http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/45/dev/update/ instead of the correct one http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/46/dev/update/.

There was also an Eclipse bug filed for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=491030).

Answer (score 0):

go to the plugins directory of your eclipse and serach using keyword "AJDT". delete all the jars that came up in search. Restart eclipse and your problem should be solved. You would need to reinstall the AJDT plugins though.